# pass session variables to another domain

Tags: node.js, express, cross-domain, express-session

It seems this cannot be easily done...if at all.

Suppose I have 2 domains, [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) and [www.mydomain.org](http://www.mydomain.org).  Each domain uses a Node.js/Express back-end and in addition both use the "express-session" module to create session information.  I wish to be able to have a user 'log in' while on one domain and have that session information pass to the other when navigation is made to the second domain.

Each domain has a 'catch-all' route that displays a 'splash' page.  This is signified by the following route:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
//do stuff and display 'splash' page...
}
```

I thought to pass the session information using a route that has a parameter containing the 'session' variable, and using that to set the 'logged in' user on the second domain.  For example:

```
app.get('/user/:client', function (req, res) {
req.session.subscriber = req.params.client;  //set the 'logged in' user on the second domain
//do stuff and display 'splash' page...
}
```

The problem is that BOTH routes seem to be called when using the route with the parameter...I suppose this makes sense since the initial route is activated using a backslash ("/")...Is there some way to correct this?

Any help about cross-domain express-session variable 'sharing' would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't know if would be helpful, check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870358/cross-domain-authentication-with-node-js-and-express-session

Comment: Thanks for the reply...not sure if that helps with my issue...but I will take a closer look at it.  Regards.